# SQL Server - inconsistent insert speed, fast then very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-performance

I'm trying to diagnose a slow insert that I thought I had fixed but the problem is returning intermittently. It's literally a straight insert statement, it runs every evening and inserts around 80,000 rows in a table with 120,000,000. The table is heavily indexed. Sometimes the insert will take under a minute and other nights it will take 15 minutes.

- There are no triggers on the table.
- I've verified the database and log have plenty of free space.
- The primary key is an identity column

I was able to reproduce a slow run of the statement and activity monitor showed the following:

Status: Suspended, Wait Type: PAGEIOLATCH_EX

I'm very confused why it runs so fast some nights and so slow others. I'm open to insights and can provide more detail if necessary.

UPDATE - I tried with various FILL FACTOR settings, no change.

Comment: Number of page splits in data and indexes.   Try rebuilding all indexes with a fill factor of 50 before the next insert.

Comment: Good call, I was thinking the same thing. The indexes are being built using the default fill factor. I'm rebuilding with 90 now and will let you know shortly.

Comment: How are you inserting?  RBAR (row by agonizing row) ? If so, can you remove the indexes....RBAR-Insert, then readd back the indexes?

Comment: @granadaCoder, don't remove the indexes, just disable any unnecessary ones and then rebuild.  But still, rebuilding indexes on a table that large just to do some inserts would most likely defeat any performance gains.

Comment: Yeah...better advice.  Disable and re-enable/rebuild.  Depends on the data being inserted.  If its fragmenting after each RBAR insert...then it would be brutally slow.

Comment: This isn't RBAR, it's one insert statement that inserts all 85000 rows. I tried with various fill factors and no improvement. I can't drop and recreate either, that takes much longer than 15 minutes as tommy_o has pointed out. Open to any other ideas.

Comment: Are you able to insert the rows in batches of 10,000 or so? Although not exactly a solution, it may help in the meantime

Comment: PAGEIOLATCH_EX latch waits happen when Sql Server is waiting for a page to be loaded from disk so it can be modified.  Sooo... Why can't your disk provide the necessary IO capacity?  Changing fill factor will just make the data bigger on disk, so if you still have PAGEIOLATCH_EX as your predominate wait type then you've made it worse.

Comment: Do you have IDENTITY (int or bigint) or Guid/UUID or something else as the Primary Key?

Comment: Identity INT as PK - granadaCoder.